# Reusing pipette tip

Tags: molecular-biology

I'm new to research and one of the things I'm learning is pipetting. I've got the basics down but say I'm reusing a pipette tip because the solution I'm using is the same. So first I depress to the first stop, aspirate liquid, then release the liquid to the second stop. However after this, do I take the pipette out and release to the very top then back down to the first stop to gather more liquid or do I take the pipette out and raise it to the first stop and gather more liquid?

Comment: Once you've depressed to the second stop, you need to remove it from the liquid, else you're re-aspirate OVER the defined amount. You also won't then be able to eject it all fully. If your pipette is set to 1000 uL, for instance, the tip volume will be 1000 uL from first stop to first stop. The second stop depression is purely there to ensure all the liquid is expelled from the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Once you dispense the liquid after the first shot, you raise the plunger back all the way to the top, and start the whole process over, as if you had a fresh tip. (the first of your two options)

Comment: One thing you should do if you are new to pipetting is to pipette water into a weigh boat on a precise scale. Pipette 100 microliters, 10 times in a row, tare, and repeat. Make sure each shot weighs 100 milligrams, just to test yourself.